# What is 'Mime' and 'MIME' in Rails 3.2 (types for file upload)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mime-types

I've inherited a project, I haven't touched mime types many times before, so I'm a bit confused here... Could anybody explain the difference between the following:

- MIME::Type
- MIME::Types
- Mime::Type

All of them are used in the application. In initialisers there is a file mime_types.rb with a comment saying that registering a new type should be simple. I had to add a 'psd' file type for upload, so it should work with something like:

```
Mime::Type.register "image/psd", :psd
```

Unfortunately in the upload functions, allowed types are checked using MIME::Types, so :psd wasn't available until I did the following:

```
psd_mime_type = MIME::Type.new('image/psd') do |t|
  t.extensions  = %w(psd)
end

MIME::Types.add psd_mime_type
```

Is this a correct usage? How one should deal with mime types check and addition of new file types for the upload?

Answer (score -1):

1- Mime types in rails is when you want to do operation with specific value like time or whatever you should define it with any method where you are needed.

```
format.ics { render :text => post.to_ics, :mime_type => Mime::Type["text/calendar"]  }
```

this article gives you better solution.

```
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html
```

2- MIME is a type of mail extension to handle smtp or http requests... :)